Detect spurious non http/https traffic on nginx and tread differently
I have a nginx server that's facing internet and listening to http and https. I am trying to process the logs (with graylog) but there is some non http/https traffic that is breaking my import process, for example in this case it seems to be FTP

59.52.103.250 - - [15/Apr/2024:08:13:00 +0200] "USER anonymous" 400 "server.example.com" 182 "-" "-" 0.694 to: -: upstream_response_time - msec 1713161580.718

While a normal conenction would be:

5.5.5.5 - - [15/Apr/2024:08:14:46 +0200] "GET /api/ HTTP/1.1" 304 "server.example.com" 0 "https://server.example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" 0.030 to: 127.0.0.1:8089: upstream_response_time 0.032 msec 1713161686.004

Is there any way to block or move to a different location anything that doesn't have http headers? I've found some posts on stackoverflow here or here but they need to explicitly list the methods allowed, I would like something that allowed all http VERBS while denying the rest.
